Recursively move and overwrite
I am using Ubuntu 24.10 and have a directory containing files and subdirectories:
main-dir
   file1
   file2
   file3
   subdir1
      file1-1
      file1-2
      subdir1-1
         file1-1-1
         file1-1-2
      subdir1-2
         file1-2-1
         subdir1-2-1
            ...

And I have a directory tree containing "corrected" files:
corrections-dir
   file2
   subdir1
      file1-1
      subdir1-1
         file1-1-1
      subdir1-2
         file1-2-1

I want to recursively move and overwrite all files from corrections-dir to main-dir. However, the mv command doesn't seem to have a recursive option. I know I could instead do this:
cp -R corrections-dir main-dir
rm -r corrections-dir

But the files are large and that command takes time and unnecessarily writes to new sectors of my SSD (thereby shortening its life).
Is there a way to use mv recursively?

Would rsync work for you?

@choroba yes, probably. I'm not entirely familiar with the rsync command and its options. Can you suggest which options I should use for this?

You can use find to do recursive operations.
cd /path/to/corrections-dir
find . -type f -exec mv -f {} /path/to/main-dir/{} \;

(untested)
This command does not handle the case of subdirectories that exist in corrections-dir but not in main-dir. I assume this was not part of the question's requirements.
Note: I use cd /path/to/corrections-dir with find . instead of find /path/to/corrections-dir because I want find to pass relative file names in {}.

You could make sure the subdirectories exist with something like find . -type d -depth -exec mkdir /path/to/main-dir/{} + 2>/dev/null.

@doneal24 I know ways how to create the target directories. I assume this is not part of the question, and I want to keep the command simple.
